smartctl & device type mismatch
I will keep it short, I am trying to better understand the different standards of storage type interfaces, but the output of smartctl is confusing me a little. Is this an actual problem in my system (like a saw on another post where some firmware was outdated) or am I misunderstanding the output of smartctl.
Observe:
> sudo smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/nvme0 -d nvme # /dev/nvme0, NVMe device

I have an HDD and an NVMe, but the HDD isn't SCSI as far as I know, unless it is "Why do my SATA devices show up under /proc/scsi/scsi?". But if it is, why can I use both -d ata and -d scsi to get information on it:
> sudo smartctl -d ata --info /dev/sda
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.10.5] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Black (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD5000BPKT-75PK4T0
Serial Number:    WD-WX11EC114329
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 6ad29b3f3
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5387
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu Aug 29 14:09:19 2024 WEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

> sudo smartctl -d scsi --info /dev/sda
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.10.5] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

User Capacity:        500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Logical Unit id:      0x50014ee6ad29b3f3
Serial number:        WD-WX11EC114329
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Thu Aug 29 14:09:35 2024 WEST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

According to the output of both, ata is clearly the "correct" type, but sudo smartctl -d ata --scan returns nothing, (unlike sudo smartctl -d scsi --scan).
Why does it seem that I can use both ata and scsi to access information, and why is it detected as scsi by --scan?

smartctl --scan is mostly name-based: ata looks for /dev/hd*, whereas /dev/sd* devices are detected as scsi.
You’ll get more reliable results with smartctl --scan-open, which will detect your ATA devices as sat. This will show the full information with --info.
You can see the type guessing done in more detail with smartctl -d test: smartctl -d test /dev/sda will show that smartctl initially guesses type scsi, then switches to sat after opening the device.
ata, sat, and scsi all work to show (some) information about SATA drives in Linux because of the way they’re handled by the Linux kernel (as SCSI devices). -d scsi shows the least information because the flag instructs smartctl to only use SCSI commands, so the information only available through ATA commands isn’t shown.
